# Unix Script Meaning

Tags: linux, shell

Could somebody please confirm the meaning of this unix script statement:

```
ls vec_tree"$i"_???.bfs > vec_tree_list$i.txt
```

I'm trying to translate it into a windows cmd code, but not sure I understand it fully. is it copying the content of the bfs file in the txt?

The statement is originally contained in a loop where $i is the iterator variable.

Answer (score 3):

the `ls` command is roughly equivalent to `dir` in windows. It lists the files it is given as arguments. By default it lists all files in the current directory

```
$ ls
file1
file2
file3
```

`"$i"` will be substituted by the value of the variable `i` in the loop.

The question mark is `?` is a wildcard that matches any single character, so in this case `???` matches any three characters.

Thus if `i=3` `vec_tree"$i"_???.bfs` would match files in your current directory like:
    vec_tree3_abc.bfs
    vec_tree3_xyz.bfs
    vec_tree3_123.bfs

`ls vec_tree"$i"_???.bfs` will actually list those files as described above.

Finally, the `> somefile` operator redirects standard output to a file `somefile`. In this case the output of the `ls` command will be written to a file called `vec_tree_list3.txt` (assuming `i=3`).

---

So overall the command will write the names of the files matching `vec_tree"$i"_???.bfs` to a file named `vec_tree_list$i.txt`

Comment: And the `ls` is actually useless and could be replaced by a simple (but not entirely trivial) `printf`, for example. All the real work is done by the shell here.

Comment: Thank you!! Is there any "translation" to use this statement in a windows bat file?

Answer (score 1):

To answer the question how to translate this to Window's cmd syntax:

The `?` operations works the same way. The iteration variable, however, is used somewhat differently `$i` -> `%i%`

So the code in your question can be translated to

```
dir vec_tree%i%_???.bfs /B > vec_tree_list%i%.txt
```

`/B` leads to an output of the files only without other information.